# CSS Responsive move div from right to underneath left and center

Tags: css, html

I want my footer inner div wrappers to mov from right to underneath left and center when I use responsive media queries. However, when moving last element "Contact us" from right to left, it goes below but it does not center, and the previous div "follow us" is not position in the same line as "copyright".

[image: The Idea Here]
[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dGBLRJ)

```
HTML
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Agency</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="footer.css" rel="stylesheet" merdia="handheld">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">

    <div class="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>  

    <div class="footer">
        <h1>Footer</h1>
            <div class="copyright">
                <h3>Copyright</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="social">
                <h3>Follow us:</h3>
                <p> Twitter, Facebook, Youtube</p>
            </div>

            <div id="contactfooter">
                <h2> Contact </h2>
                <p>Contact Form would go here</p>
            </div>
    </div>
 </body>
```

```
CSS
 /*footer.css*/
 *{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

body
{
 background-color:#DCDCDC;
}

.wrapper{
max-width:1200px;
width:100%;
margin:auto;    
}

.header{
width:100%;
background-color:green;
height:20vh;
}

.footer{
width:100%;
background-color:orange;
font-size:1em;
overflow:hidden;
padding-bottom:3%;
clear:both;
padding-top:5%;
border-top:3px solid #0099FF;
color:black;
}

.copyright{
width:25%;
background-color:red;
float:left;
margin-left:10%;    
}

.copyright p{

font-size:0.938em;
line-height: 2em;
}

.social{
width:20%;
background-color:yellow;
float:left;
margin-left:8%;
}

#contactfooter{
width:20%;
background-color:blue;
float:right;
margin-right:10%;
display:block;
}

#contactfooter h2, #contactfooter{
    font-size:1.250em;
    text-align: center;
}

/*---------MEDIA QUERIES----------*/

 @media (max-width:1020px){
.copyright{
    margin-left:25%;
    float:left;
  }
.social{
    float:right;
    margin-right:25%;
}

#contactfooter{
    float:left;
    width:30%;
    margin:auto; /*does not margin to the center of the footer wrapper.. why?*/
    /*margin-right:0%;
    margin-left:45%;*/


   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to change their margins for smaller screens, just fix their width.